# Unable to get result of JsonPath expression when used with print keyword in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I have a JSON as below -

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

In the feature file -

```
* print jsonObject.store.book[1].author
* def allAuthors1 = get jsonObject.store.book[*].author
* print allAuthors1
* print jsonObject.store.book[*].author
```

For #1 = Expected output

For #2, #3 = Expected output

For #4 = When I try directly to print without storing in a variable - Syntax error

> SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:43 Expected an operand but found *
> karate.log('[print]',jsonObject.store.book[*].author)

```
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` keyword does NOT support JsonPath. Only JS.

Do it in two steps:

```
* def temp = $jsonObject.store.book[*].author
* print temp
```

You could of course use `karate.jsonPath()`

```
* print karate.jsonPath(jsonObject, '$.store.book[*].author')
```

`karate.get()` should also work:

```
* print karate.get('$jsonObject.store.book[*].author')
```

Comment: "The print keyword does NOT support JsonPath" - It seems to be true if we use any special chars like *, ? etc. Because * print jsonObject.store.book[1].author works perfectly fine.

Comment: yes, because without `?` or `*` or `..` it is just JS